# How to disable activiti REST HTTP

Tags: spring-boot, basic-authentication, activiti

We are using activiti v5.18 and spring boot. To invoke activiti REST API, we have to create an activiti user to pass basic authentication. As I know, activiti security is based on spring boot security, we tried two approaches.

1. Exclude activiti spring boot security auto config

   ```
   @EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = {org.activiti.spring.boot.SecurityAutoConfiguration.class})
   ```
2. Create a class to extend spring class 'WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter), and set 'security.basic.enabled=false' in application.properties

   ```
   @Configuration
   @EnableWebSecurity
   @EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
   @Order(SecurityProperties.ACCESS_OVERRIDE_ORDER)
   public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

   @Override
   protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

   // @formatter:off
   http
   .authorizeRequests()
   .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/","/static/**", "/resources/**","/resources/public/**").permitAll()
   .anyRequest().authenticated()
   .and()
   .formLogin()
   .and()
   .httpBasic().disable()
   .requiresChannel().anyRequest().requiresSecure();
   // @formatter:on
   }
   }
   ```

Unfortunately, none of them disable the basic authentication, when I go to page 'http://localhost:8080/repository/deployments', browser pops up user login window. And show error message on page

This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

There was an unexpected error (type=Unauthorized, status=401).
Full authentication is required to access this resource

In addition, we have our own REST service, when client invoke our REST service, browser also asks to input activiti REST user/password.

Is there any way to disable activiti REST HTTP basic authentication?

Answer (score 3):

You could use antMatchers to disable authentication for some type of requests such as HTTP-GET or / and HTTP-POST requests as follows:

```
.antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/**").permitAll()
```

With his command, all HTTP-GET Methods won´t hit the `BasicAuthenticationFilter`. For my UseCase, I had to exclude the HTTP-Options Requests this way. Simply edit the `org.activiti.rest.conf.SecurityConfiguration.java` in the `activiti-webapp-rest2` as follows:

```
@Override
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
     http
     .authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider())
     .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).and()
     .csrf().disable()
     .authorizeRequests()
     .antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/**").permitAll()
     .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/**").permitAll()
     .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/**").permitAll()
     .antMatchers(HttpMethod.PUT, "/**").permitAll()
     .antMatchers(HttpMethod.DELETE, "/**").permitAll()
       .anyRequest().authenticated()
       .and()
     .httpBasic();
  }
```

After that, you have to rebuild the Activiti-Project. Redeploy the war-file and after that, basic auth should be disabled.

Comment: Hi, I would like to use waffle and custom authentication impl, instead of the basic authentication in activiti, so I need to do what you wrote, and then where do I make my own authentication and reply with a TRUE to the validation function ? where should I put the breakpoint in the code ?

Comment: For custom authentication, implement a custom authentication filter public class CustomAuthenticationFilter extends AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter. Within this filter, you make your authentication. In the spring java config, declare your filter as a bean:
\@Bean
 public CustomAuthenticationFilter customTokenAuthenticationFilter(){
  return new CustomAuthenticationFilter ("/**");};

\@Autowired
CustomAuthenticationFilter customTokenAuthenticationFilter;

and use .addFilterBefore(customTokenAuthenticationFilter, BasicAuthenticationFilter.class).httpBasic();
to add your filter to chain.

Comment: Hi, Where is the spring conf file ? when hosted in activiti rest ?

Comment: under the activiti-webapp-rest2 --> org.activiti.rest.conf.SecurityConfiguration.java

Comment: @Ben i have same problem but not solve. please help me. thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This might be coming late for the OP, but this work and probably still will help other people.

```java
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = {
org.activiti.spring.boot.RestApiAutoConfiguration.class,
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.SecurityAutoConfiguration.class,
org.activiti.spring.boot.SecurityAutoConfiguration.class,
org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.ManagementWebSecurityAutoConfiguration.class
})
```

Comment: https://forums.activiti.org/content/disable-activiti-spring-rest-api-basic-authentication

Answer (score 0):

you can use this class for configuration with [@Ben](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2384597/ben) idea:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableWebMvcSecurity
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
public class CustomSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Bean
    @ConditionalOnMissingBean
    public AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
        return new BasicAuthenticationProvider();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider())
                .csrf().disable()
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.PUT, "/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.DELETE, "/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .httpBasic();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Recently I was also faced with this issue. I tried several suggestions and spent many hours but I could not succeed. But there was very easy way out. If one doesnt need to use the Activiti-rest while integrating it with one's application as such then just take the dependency

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.activiti</groupId>
<artifactId>activiti-spring-boot-starter-rest-api</artifactId>
<version>${activiti.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

out.
Hope it will help someone. There is no documentation I could find mentioning this.